# Passing parameter to Stored Procedure using DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which accepts one string parameter, below is my code

```
var databaseContext = (DbContext)this.ManagementContext;
databaseContext.Database.Connection.Open();
using (var command = databaseContext.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
{
command.CommandText = "StoredProcName";
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
DbParameter param = command.CreateParameter();
param.DbType = DbType.String;
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
param.Value = "Vikash";
command.Parameters.Add(param);
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
```

My stored procedure is not getting value in parameter.

Comment: You're not giving the parameter a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed your ParameterName in your code. Try this,

```
        using (var ctx = new StOflowContext())
        {
            ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
            using (var command = ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                DbParameter param = command.CreateParameter();
                param.ParameterName = "@paramName";
                param.DbType = DbType.String;
                param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                param.Value = "Vikash";

                command.Parameters.Add(param);
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())

                { 
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and it works fine.

```
var dateParameter = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "CastID", Value = castMember, DbType = DbType.String, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input };
                    command.Parameters.Add(dateParameter);
```

Answer (score -1):

If your stored procedure is named "StoredProcName", and execute with parameter named "Para1".

```
var executedResult =
            ((IObjectContextAdapter) this).databaseContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(
                "StoredProcName @Para1", "Vikash");
```

then, you'll get stored procedure result in "executedResult".

Comment: Not much help from this, can u give one small example here.

Comment: is the example is fine for you?