# SqlException expecting parameter when passed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting a `SqlException`

> Procedure or function 'GetDashboardData' expects parameter '@userID', which was not supplied.

I have been trying to follow this post, however does not seem to cater for passing parameters.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx and then looked for fixes

I have then continued to try and pass it a parameter but got this exception thrown (shown above) and googled around. I have tried the first answer post in this post as it seems the most relevant and quickest way

[Passing parameter to Stored Procedure using DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099826/passing-parameter-to-stored-procedure-using-dbcontext)

However this did not work so was wondering how do I go about passing this parameter?

```
string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();

// If using code first we need to make sure the model built before we open a connection
db.Database.Initialize(force: false);
var command = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetDashboardData]";

var userIDParameter = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@userID", Value = userID, DbType = DbType.String, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input };
command.Parameters.Add(userIDParameter);

try 
{
    db.Database.Connection.Open();

    // We now run the stored procedure
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    var getUserDashboards = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<DashboardModel>(reader, "DashboardModel", MergeOption.AppendOnly);
}
finally
{
    db.Database.Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged this any? Maybe your userid var is empty?

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv it does indeed contain a value and that value

Comment: Have you specified a command type as stored procedure? command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: Also remove the "@" from the parameter name when declaring the sql parameter.

Comment: What is the database type of the SQL parameter?